# How do I create an Access form which updates a table in a SQL Server View

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am porting an Access front end/Access back end application to Access front end/SQL Server back end and am having trouble with a particular form.  I think its because I do not properly understand the underlying concepts in what I am trying to do. In particular Updating Data through a view.

Its a resource booking application, where I have "clients", known primarily through their clientID trying to book a "resource" (known by its resourceID) in a "diary".  Each record in the "diary" is a booking, containing the date and time of the booking together with the clientID and resourceID.

In the existing Access application I have a query as the record source for the form which joins the diary and client via their mutual clientID.  Something along these lines (although in the real thing many more fields are involved)

```
SELECT d.bookdate,d.booktime, d.clientID, c.clientID AS CID, c.name
FROM diary d INNER JOIN client c ON d.clientID = c.clientID
ORDER BY bookdate,booktime
```

I find that I can create a new diary record for a clientID by opening the form with 
acFormAdd and OpenArgs set to clientID, and writing that in form load to a form field liked to the data field CID (c.clientID), thus

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDiary", acNormal, , "ClientID = " & Me.ClientID, acFormAdd, , Me.ClientID
```

and then in frmDiary in the Form_Current sub

```
    If Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "") <> "" Then Me.CID = Me.OpenArgs
```

the writing of the Me.CID field (which is the side of the query where the data already exists) causes a new record to be created in the diary table and at the same time populates the form with the correct data from the other fields from the Client Record.

In the SQL Server version of the application I dynamically create tabledefs to point to the tables in the correct instance of my SQL Server database during an initiation sequence.  I also create tabledefs for appropriate views.  I do it dynamically to enable me to switch between various versions of my database very easily.

Because my diary table is 80,000 records long and the client table is 40000 records long, I don't particularly what the join of the two to take place in the Access client.  I have therefore created a View on SQL Server that matches the select clause above (minus the order by) and created a tabledef for it during initialisation.

However the whole form does not work because it tells me the view is not updateable.  This seems to be confirmed by opening the tabledef in as a datasheet in Access - there is no new record button in the navigation set.

I am struggling because

1. I don't understand how the db_datawriter role translates into privileges to write to the database.  (my application connects as a server login which matches a database user who has the db_datawriter role assigned). So I have no idea if this extends to the view and whether my issue is a permissions issue.  I am exploring the database with SQL Server Management Studio and looking at permission properties.
2. I have read that only fields in a view that belong to one of the base tables from which the view is constructed can be updated.  This makes my "trick" of writing the Me.CID field of my form to stimulate creation of the new diary record appear not to be the right approach.

So I am not sure what my next step should be. Any ideas?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my "diary" table.  I've just tried to insert a record directly in SQL Server Management Studio without the Primary Key (which should be the IDENTITY column) and it fails with Primary Key Violation.  I had to switch off this to load the table from access when I migrated the table a little while ago, and it looks like it may not have switched back on correctly

Comment: I found out the problem, my migration routine had done a DBCC CHECKIDENT ( diary, RESEED,0 ) and I think it should have done DBCC CHECKIDENT (diary,RESEED).  Anyway, I have just done the latter and it has solved the problem.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key elements of my question was "How do you make a view Updateable?".  The simple answer it to give it a UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX.

I found that although you can create on a view, if you ever alter the view (like to add an additional field) you need to recreate the index because it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

is this the code of the view?

```
SELECT d.bookdate,d.booktime, d.clientID, c.clientID AS CID, c.name
FROM diary d INNER JOIN client c ON d.clientID = c.clientID
ORDER BY bookdate,booktime
```

if it is you wont be able to update the view. You can only use a view to update a table if there is only one table on the view. From MSDN:

```
Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from only one base table
```

But why do you need to use the view to update?

regarding the db_datawriter, you are right. If a login is mapped to a user with db_datawriter, you 
shouldn't face permission problems when writing data.

Comment: that is the view, which is the recordsource of the form.  However the second table fields are view only and are locked.  I need to update the dairy table because that is one of the purposes of the form. (In the Access Backend version this record source is a query)